# Gitlab-ci: Getting error when I use rules and downstream pipeline trigger in the same stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to trigger downstream pipeline but before that I need to eliminate the branches with rule method and I just want to trigger it only with specific branches. But I'm getting this error when I run the pipeline `downstream pipeline cannot be created reference not found` Did I miss something or can't I use rule and trigger methods in the same stage?

My stage:

```
test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    branch: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  trigger:
    project: test/project
    strategy: depend
    branch: $branch
  allow_failure: false
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main' || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'test'
    - when: never
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the dash on the last line is [not needed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules). Probably you meant this:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main' || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'test'
      when: never
```

I also recommend to check [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`:

> The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including
> pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request
> pipelines or tag pipelines.

You could try to use $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME variable instead which is available in merge request or tag pipelines. You could try to debug this adding some echo commands (like `- echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` and `- echo $branch` to be sure that the branch really exists in the downstream project and variable are properly expanded.

But first of all you need to fix the syntax (that extra dash).

Comment: thank you for you suggestion. I updated my code but I think the problem is not caused by that. I created new question with my whole pipeline concept. Can you also check that maybe we will help :) [my_question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75319952/21108939)